# Vim Regex Split Line from Lower case characters

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to seperate titles from text, titles and first paragraph of text is inline.

```
<p>GUSLÜN SÜNNETLERİ VE BAZI İNCELİKLERİ Gusle niyet ederek, Besmele ve misvâk ile başlamak. Evvelâ elleri, oyluk yerlerini yıkamak, bedende meni vesâire eseri varsa gidermek.</p>
```

The regex command below only catches the first UPPERCASE word. I need to define the character set explicitly because of non ascii characters (like `Â, Î, Û`) . And I used `!` instead of forward slash `/`.

```
%s!\v(<[ABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKMLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZÎÂÛ]{2,}>{-1,})(.*)$!<h2>\1</h2>\r\r\2!g
```

The excepted result is

```
<p>
<h2>GUSLÜN SÜNNETLERİ VE BAZI İNCELİKLERİ</h2>

Gusle niyet ederek, Besmele ve misvâk ile başlamak.Evvelâ elleri, oyluk yerlerini yıkamak, bedende meni vesâire eseri varsa gidermek.</p>
```

**Tip:** Finding the last occurence of UPPERCASE word, also can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a "non unicode unicode character"?  Maybe you want to edit the question?

The `$` in `(.*)$` is redundant, since `*` is greedy.  Since you end up putting `\2` at the end of the replacement pattern, you can simplify the command by not capturing and replacing the second part at all:

```
:s!<pattern>!<h2>\1</h2>\r\r!
```

(The `g` flag at the end was also redundant.)

If you set `'iskeyword'` correctly, then `\k` will match word characters properly, but unfortunately `\u` ignores this setting, stubbornly matching only ASCII upper-case letters.  But you can simplify your character class to `[A-ZÇĞİÖŞÜÎÂÛ]` (unless it is important to exclude Q, W, and X).  With these simplifications, rednaw's answer becomes

```
:s!\v((<[A-ZÇĞİÖŞÜÎÂÛ]{2,}>{-1,}\s*)+)\s+!<h2>\1</h2>\r\r!
```

To find the last uppercase word in a line, try

```
 /\v.*\zs<[A-ZÇĞİÖŞÜÎÂÛ]{2,}
```

For details, see

```
:help /\k
:help 'iskeyword'
:help /[]
:help /\zs
:help pattern
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
%s!\v((<[ABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKMLMNOÖPRSŞTUÜVYZÎÂÛ]{2,}>{-1,}\s*)+)\s+(.*)$!<h2>\1</h2>\r\r\3!g
```